# Complex variable limit at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, infinity

Is $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty} \frac{4z^2}{(z-1)^2}$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$, evaluated the same way as a real variable function limit? Or does one need to show separate cases for $x\to\infty$ and $y\to\infty$ in $z:=x+iy$? Got confused.

Comment: More than just $x\to \infty$ and $y\to \infty$, you should consider $\lvert z\rvert \to \infty$. (That's the meaning of "$z\to\infty$" here.)

Comment: @ClementC. we can consider the change of variable $u=\frac{1}{z}$. But how to go from there?

Comment: You are looking for the limit of $\frac{4z^2}{(z-1)^2}$ when $\lvert z\rvert \to \infty$, so you can safely assume $z \neq 0$ and factor by $z$. Doing so, you obtain:
$$
\frac{4z^2}{(z-1)^2} = \frac{4}{(1-1/z)^2}
$$
and it remains to show than the denominator goes to $1$ (e.g., by using the fact that $1/z\to 0$ since $1/\lvert z\rvert\to 0$).